# Mod Tools/Panel: Misaligned "Flag Types" Section

Tags: bug, status-norepro

This must have changed within the past couple hours, but where we would normally see that nice sidebar in the mod panel with all the flag types and such no longer appears there, where the red freeform drawing is:

[image]

It's not *gone* entirely, though, it's just no longer aligned properly... at the far bottom of the page *under* all the flags where it's not useful:

[image]

Now, about 6 hours ago when I left for home after work, the panel appeared where the red freehand drawings were.  So has something changed in the past 6 hours to cause this?  Same browser, same computer, nothing's changed... except possibly the site theme...

(Note that I tried as hard as possible to black out any type of data that otherwise shouldn't be seen by standard users... delete the screenshots if this is still 'too much' being shown)

Comment: Do you still see this? Seems fine to me.

Comment: @terron clearing the r/a flag seemed to clear it, will report again when in front of a computer.

Comment: Looks like this issue has since resolved itself, or been a temporary transient one.  :|